# jQuery document.ready not wotking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello world');
}
</script>
```

I know no typo error in this function. but still, it not alerting me when a document is ready. You can check live on http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Lost/step_2 please please help me and sorry for weak English.

Comment: Typo - `}` instead of `})`.

Comment: } instead of});

Comment: For future reference always check the console for errors when JS code doesn't behave as you expect it to. In this case you would have been told about the typo

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `)` of `ready` function

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('hello world');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your function is not correct. You forgot the last parenthesis.

The correct is

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello world');
})
</script>
```

check it